# In Cypress how do we return array from method and pass the returned array value as parameter to another method

Tags: cypress

Let say I want to store the multiple elements and return the array to another method as a parameter.Currently I am using cucumber with cypress tool,In simple I want to return the array from step definition and make use of this array as parameter in another step definition,how to do with cypress tool?,Please someone guide me.

Comment: The test scenario should be decribed better, maybe add some code examples and specify your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The main concept of sharing data in test is [aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html)

```
// when step
cy.wrap([1,2 3 4 5]).as('myElements')

// then step
cy.get('@myElements').then(elements => {
// pass it to command as parameter.
})
```

Moreover, you can setup your custom command as [child](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Child-Commands) and use 'prevSubject' to point out that it should receive result of previous command as argument:

```
// command:
Cypress.Commands.add('myCommand', {
  prevSubject: true
}, (elements) => {})

// usage:
cy.get('@myElements').myCommand()
```

Comment: Hi Oleksandr,Can you please ellaborate by showing dropdown as example with some real time data please.// when step
cy.wrap([1,2 3 4 5]).as('myElements')

// then step
cy.get('@myElements').then(elements => {
// pass it to command as parameter.
})

Comment: I tried with this,                                                                                                                            // when step
cy.get(this.testArray).each(($$el, index, $list) => {
   cy.wrap($$el.text()).as("testData");
  });

// then step
cy.get("@testData").then((elements) => {
   cy.log(elements);
  });                                                                                                                           Here,it is printing only one data instead of multiple data,Please correct me where I have done the mistake.

Comment: If you want to write whole array to alias you should not iterate every element, just: `cy.wrap(this.testArray).as('@testData')`. Moreover, your question was about array of elements, not TEXT from this elements. In case you need array of texts try [cypress-commands](https://github.com/Lakitna/cypress-commands) and use `cy.text()` - it will produce texts from array of elements. Example: `cy.wrap(this.testArray).text().as('testData')`